# bind the click event to all links in a div with a certain class name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

The first parts of the jquery call inside the document.ready is pseudo code. How can I do the  $('.mainLink').each().click() correctly so that all links with class name mainLinks inside the NavigationPanel are bound to the click event. Is it bad to not use an id for a link?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.mainLink').each().click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();                
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    beforeSend: OnBegin,
                    complete: OnComplete,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#ContentPanel').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        });  

<div id="NavigationPanel">  

        @Html.ActionLink("1", "Index", "First", null, new { @class = "mainLink" })
        @Html.ActionLink("2", "Index", "Two", null, new { @class = "mainLink"  })
        @Html.ActionLink("3", "Index", "Three", null, new { @class = "mainLink" })    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `$('.mainLink').click(function (e) {` which should bind all links with class `.mainLink`

If you want all links inside div ID `NavigationPanel` then try below,

`$('.mainLink', $('#NavigationPanel')).click(function (e) {`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to bind to all `.mainLink` within `#NavigationPanel`, the following works:

```
$("#NavigationPanel").on("click", ".mainLink", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();                
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        beforeSend: OnBegin,
        complete: OnComplete,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#ContentPanel').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```